# How to style textbox with silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-2010

I need 3 textboxes under each other. I want it to looks like a big display. So dont want to seen the separation lines between each textbox. Somebody told me to use Silverlight style for that. Bud i have no idea how to change it in Visual studio 2010. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use Silverlight at all.

If you have 3 textboxes right below each other. Set their `BorderStyle` to none. Maybe wrap them in a Panel and make the panel `BorderStyle` to Fixed3D, you can make it look like one big area when in fact it is 3 textboxes.

Answer (score 0):

I've answered this in the original question - [How to use multilines in textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714030/how-to-use-multilines-in-textbox/5714097#5714097)